# Which cms page = homepage

Tags: magento-1.9.3.2

In `cms - pages` there isn't a page for sites homepage. There is one that should be the homepage but disabling/editing it does nothing.

How to figure out where the homepage is getting it's content/design?

Answer (score 0):

> You have to go **CMS** in Admin Top menu.
>
> Then Select menu **Pages**
>
> And find column named **url_key** is **home**

You will find all home page regard content here.

Comment: By in "Admin" you mean on server side?
Cause in Magento i can't find such options.

Comment: In the admin side, Open your Magento Admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

**Admin DashBoard**

```
Step 1:
CMS > Pages > Manage Content > filter URL key = home
```

**Check which CMS page select for Home Page**

```
Step 2:
System > Configuration > General > Web > Default Pages > CMS Home Page
```

Hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: I've tried that.
https://imgur.com/RxqIkRD - Settings of Default pages.

https://imgur.com/5aKkVkh - List of CMS pages

Doesn't matter what i save as default cms homepage, it doesnt affect the website.

Comment: check Current Configuration Scope:

Comment: You mean the store opts. under "current configuration scope"?
All are set to use the "Use Website [STORE VIEW]"

Main problem is that i can't find the actual CMS page from which the homepages design is coming from. I have disabled both cms pages that should be the homepage and checked all of the others. No effect.

Comment: while config are correct and cms page are disable -> then this is cache issue, you check in new browser. and 
2 step is -> make new cms page assign in config then check the effect...

Comment: I've cleared/flushed cache to no success.
Tried step 2 on all store view's, didnt work either.

What should i set as the "url key" for homepage?
https://www.audiocity.ee/ - the version with messed up cms.
https://www.audiocity.ee/avaleht - With the url key added to cms its more like it should be.

The problem extends to other pages aswell, i can't add/remove static blocks to categories.